# Register multiple static IP addresses ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, static-ip

I currently have 1 static IP registered on my server.  I'd like to go ahead and register 4 other static addresses.  I'm not sure of the syntax.  Should I just do `iface eth0:0 inet static`?

Here's what I have now:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
      address xxx.xxx.xx.xx
      netmask xxx.xxx.xx.xx
      gateway xxx.xxx.xx.xx
      broadcast xxx.xxx.xx.xx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 auto eth0:0
 iface eth0:0 inet static
         address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
         netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
         broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Don't add more gateway entries because you'll have multiple default routes.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to [MihaiM](https://serverfault.com/users/48323/mihaim) suggestion I like to setup my configuration like this.  That way all the addresses for a interface and all the addresses can be brought up with a single command (`ifup eth0`) or down (`ifdown eth0`).

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.32.5
        netmask 255.255.255.192
        network 192.168.32.0
        broadcast 192.168.32.63
        # listen on additional addresses
        up ip addr add 192.168.32.6/26 brd + dev eth0
        up ip addr add 192.168.32.7/26 brd + dev eth0
        down ip addr del 192.168.32.6/26 brd + dev eth0
        down ip addr del 192.168.32.7/26 brd + dev eth0
```